# Fatal Exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fatal Exception thrown on Scheduler.Worker thread

Tags: android, multithreading, retrofit, rx-java, rx-android

I'm getting a crash while making a network call using retrofit. Here is my stacktrace.

```
    Fatal Exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fatal Exception thrown on Scheduler.Worker thread.
       at rx.internal.schedulers.ScheduledAction.run(ScheduledAction.java:62)
       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5584)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Method.java)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1268)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1084)
       at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(NativeStart.java)
Caused by rx.b.i: Error occurred when trying to propagate error to Observer.onError
       at rx.observers.SafeSubscriber._onError(SafeSubscriber.java:2192)
       at rx.internal.operators.OperatorDoOnEach$1.onError(OperatorDoOnEach.java:71)
       at rx.observers.SerializedObserver.onError(SerializedObserver.java:158)
       at rx.observers.SerializedSubscriber.onError(SerializedSubscriber.java:79)
       at rx.internal.operators.OperatorTakeUntil$1.onError(OperatorTakeUntil.java:49)
       at rx.internal.operators.OperatorToObservableList$1.onError(OperatorToObservableList.java:99)
       at rx.internal.operators.OperatorFilter$1.onError(OperatorFilter.java:47)
       at rx.internal.operators.OperatorMerge$MergeSubscriber.reportError(OperatorMerge.java:243)
       at rx.internal.operators.OperatorMerge$MergeSubscriber.checkTerminate(OperatorMerge.java:779)
       at rx.internal.operators.OperatorMerge$MergeSubscriber.emitLoop(OperatorMerge.java:540)
       at rx.internal.operators.OperatorMerge$MergeSubscriber.emit(OperatorMerge.java:529)
       at rx.internal.operators.OperatorMerge$MergeSubscriber.onError(OperatorMerge.java:253)
       at rx.internal.operators.OperatorMap$1.onError(OperatorMap.java:48)
       at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeRedo$4$1.onError(OnSubscribeRedo.java:331)
       at rx.internal.operators.OperatorMerge$MergeSubscriber.reportError(OperatorMerge.java:243)
       at rx.internal.operators.OperatorMerge$MergeSubscriber.checkTerminate(OperatorMerge.java:779)
       at rx.internal.operators.OperatorMerge$MergeSubscriber.emitLoop(OperatorMerge.java:540)
       at rx.internal.operators.OperatorMerge$MergeSubscriber.emit(OperatorMerge.java:529)
       at rx.internal.operators.OperatorMerge$InnerSubscriber.onError(OperatorMerge.java:813)
       at rx.Observable$ThrowObservable$1.call(Observable.java:11200)
       at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:8314)
       at rx.internal.operators.OperatorMerge$MergeSubscriber.onNext(OperatorMerge.java:7235)
       at rx.internal.operators.OperatorMap$1.onNext(OperatorMap.java:54)
       at rx.internal.operators.OperatorMap$1.onNext(OperatorMap.java:54)
       at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeRedo$3$1.onNext(OnSubscribeRedo.java:1307)
       at rx.internal.operators.NotificationLite.accept(NotificationLite.java:150)
       at rx.subjects.SubjectSubscriptionManager$SubjectObserver.emitNext$a2d69e2(SubjectSubscriptionManager.java:253)
       at rx.subjects.BehaviorSubject.onNext(BehaviorSubject.java:160)
       at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeRedo$2$1.onError(OnSubscribeRedo.java:242)
       at rx.internal.operators.OperatorObserveOn$ObserveOnSubscriber.checkTerminated(OperatorObserveOn.java:254)
       at rx.internal.operators.OperatorObserveOn$ObserveOnSubscriber.call(OperatorObserveOn.java:186)
       at rx.internal.schedulers.ScheduledAction.run(ScheduledAction.java:55)
       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5584)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Method.java)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1268)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1084)
       at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(NativeStart.java)
Caused by rx.b.a: 2 exceptions occurred. 
       at rx.observers.SafeSubscriber._onError(SafeSubscriber.java:2192)
       at rx.internal.operators.OperatorDoOnEach$1.onError(OperatorDoOnEach.java:71)
       at rx.observers.SerializedObserver.onError(SerializedObserver.java:158)
       at rx.observers.SerializedSubscriber.onError(SerializedSubscriber.java:79)
       at rx.internal.operators.OperatorTakeUntil$1.onError(OperatorTakeUntil.java:49)
       at rx.internal.operators.OperatorToObservableList$1.onError(OperatorToObservableList.java:99)
       at rx.internal.operators.OperatorFilter$1.onError(OperatorFilter.java:47)
       at rx.internal.operators.OperatorMerge$MergeSubscriber.reportError(OperatorMerge.java:243)
       at rx.internal.operators.OperatorMerge$MergeSubscriber.checkTerminate(OperatorMerge.java:779)
       at rx.internal.operators.OperatorMerge$MergeSubscriber.emitLoop(OperatorMerge.java:540)
       at rx.internal.operators.OperatorMerge$MergeSubscriber.emit(OperatorMerge.java:529)
       at rx.internal.operators.OperatorMerge$MergeSubscriber.onError(OperatorMerge.java:253)
       at rx.internal.operators.OperatorMap$1.onError(OperatorMap.java:48)
       at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeRedo$4$1.onError(OnSubscribeRedo.java:331)
       at rx.internal.operators.OperatorMerge$MergeSubscriber.reportError(OperatorMerge.java:243)
       at rx.internal.operators.OperatorMerge$MergeSubscriber.checkTerminate(OperatorMerge.java:779)
       at rx.internal.operators.OperatorMerge$MergeSubscriber.emitLoop(OperatorMerge.java:540)
       at rx.internal.operators.OperatorMerge$MergeSubscriber.emit(OperatorMerge.java:529)
       at rx.internal.operators.OperatorMerge$InnerSubscriber.onError(OperatorMerge.java:813)
       at rx.Observable$ThrowObservable$1.call(Observable.java:11200)
       at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:8314)
       at rx.internal.operators.OperatorMerge$MergeSubscriber.onNext(OperatorMerge.java:7235)
       at rx.internal.operators.OperatorMap$1.onNext(OperatorMap.java:54)
       at rx.internal.operators.OperatorMap$1.onNext(OperatorMap.java:54)
       at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeRedo$3$1.onNext(OnSubscribeRedo.java:1307)
       at rx.internal.operators.NotificationLite.accept(NotificationLite.java:150)
       at rx.subjects.SubjectSubscriptionManager$SubjectObserver.emitNext$a2d69e2(SubjectSubscriptionManager.java:253)
       at rx.subjects.BehaviorSubject.onNext(BehaviorSubject.java:160)
       at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeRedo$2$1.onError(OnSubscribeRedo.java:242)
       at rx.internal.operators.OperatorObserveOn$ObserveOnSubscriber.checkTerminated(OperatorObserveOn.java:254)
       at rx.internal.operators.OperatorObserveOn$ObserveOnSubscriber.call(OperatorObserveOn.java:186)
       at rx.internal.schedulers.ScheduledAction.run(ScheduledAction.java:55)
       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5584)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Method.java)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1268)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1084)
       at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(NativeStart.java)
Caused by rx.b.b: Chain of Causes for CompositeException In Order Received =>
       at com.crashlytics.android.core.SessionProtobufHelper.getEventAppExecutionExceptionSize(SessionProtobufHelper.java:619)
       at com.crashlytics.android.core.SessionProtobufHelper.getEventAppExecutionExceptionSize(SessionProtobufHelper.java:622)
       at com.crashlytics.android.core.SessionProtobufHelper.getEventAppExecutionExceptionSize(SessionProtobufHelper.java:622)
       at com.crashlytics.android.core.SessionProtobufHelper.getEventAppExecutionSize$322e56cf(SessionProtobufHelper.java:554)
       at com.crashlytics.android.core.SessionProtobufHelper.getEventAppSize$565823c3(SessionProtobufHelper.java:510)
       at com.crashlytics.android.core.SessionProtobufHelper.getSessionEventSize(SessionProtobufHelper.java:2482)
       at com.crashlytics.android.core.CrashlyticsUncaughtExceptionHandler.writeSessionEvent$13f1f7ff(CrashlyticsUncaughtExceptionHandler.java:1052)
       at com.crashlytics.android.core.CrashlyticsUncaughtExceptionHandler.writeFatal(CrashlyticsUncaughtExceptionHandler.java:23766)
       at com.crashlytics.android.core.CrashlyticsUncaughtExceptionHandler$5.call(CrashlyticsUncaughtExceptionHandler.java:1238)
       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
       at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.common.ExecutorUtils$1$1.onRun(ExecutorUtils.java:75)
       at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.common.BackgroundPriorityRunnable.run(BackgroundPriorityRunnable.java:30)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
Caused by retrofit.RetrofitError
       at retrofit.RestAdapter$RestHandler.invokeRequest(RestAdapter.java:395)
       at retrofit.RestAdapter$RestHandler.invoke(RestAdapter.java:240)
       at $Proxy4.getChartStockData(Unknown Source)
       at com.talkoot.android.web.GoogleFinanceManager.access$lambda$0(GoogleFinanceManager.java:1082)
       at com.talkoot.android.web.GoogleFinanceManager$$Lambda$1.call(Unknown Source)
       at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeFromCallable.call(OnSubscribeFromCallable.java:1032)
       at rx.Observable$2.call(Observable.java:1162)
       at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:8314)
       at rx.internal.operators.OperatorSubscribeOn$1.call(OperatorSubscribeOn.java:94)
       at rx.internal.schedulers.ScheduledAction.run(ScheduledAction.java:55)
       at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:422)
       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
       at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:152)
       at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:265)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
Caused by java.net.SocketTimeoutException
       at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.read(PlainSocketImpl.java:491)
       at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.access$000(PlainSocketImpl.java:46)
       at java.net.PlainSocketImpl$PlainSocketInputStream.read(PlainSocketImpl.java:240)
       at java.io.InputStream.read(InputStream.java:162)
       at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fillbuf(BufferedInputStream.java:142)
       at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:227)
       at com.android.okhttp.internal.Util.readAsciiLine(Util.java:316)
       at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RawHeaders.fromBytes(RawHeaders.java:308)
       at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpTransport.readResponseHeaders(HttpTransport.java:135)
       at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.readResponse(HttpEngine.java:644)
       at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:347)
       at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:296)
       at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:503)
       at retrofit.client.UrlConnectionClient.readResponse(UrlConnectionClient.java:73)
       at retrofit.client.UrlConnectionClient.execute(UrlConnectionClient.java:38)
       at retrofit.RestAdapter$RestHandler.invokeRequest(RestAdapter.java:326)
       at retrofit.RestAdapter$RestHandler.invoke(RestAdapter.java:240)
       at $Proxy4.getChartStockData(Unknown Source)
       at com.talkoot.android.web.GoogleFinanceManager.access$lambda$0(GoogleFinanceManager.java:1082)
       at com.talkoot.android.web.GoogleFinanceManager$$Lambda$1.call(Unknown Source)
       at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeFromCallable.call(OnSubscribeFromCallable.java:1032)
       at rx.Observable$2.call(Observable.java:1162)
       at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:8314)
       at rx.internal.operators.OperatorSubscribeOn$1.call(OperatorSubscribeOn.java:94)
       at rx.internal.schedulers.ScheduledAction.run(ScheduledAction.java:55)
       at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:422)
       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
       at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:152)
       at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:265)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

Here is my code.

```
 public void downloadChartFullData(@NonNull String ticker, @NonNull String exchange, @NonNull ChartTimePeriod chartTimePeriod,
                                      @NonNull ChartFragment fragment) {
        if (!ConnectionUtils.isNetworkConnected(false))
            return;
        Log.v(TAG + Utils.getCurrentThreadInfo(), "handleActionDownloadChartStockData");
        getChartStockData(ticker, exchange)
                .compose(fragment.bindToLifecycle())
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .retryWhen(RetryWithDelay.newInstance())
                .flatMap(new Func1<List<ChartDataEntity>, Observable<ChartDataEntity>>() {
                    @Override
                    public Observable<ChartDataEntity> call(List<ChartDataEntity> stockEntities) {
                        return Observable.from(stockEntities);
                    }
                })
                .filter(new Func1<ChartDataEntity, Boolean>() {
                    @Override
                    public Boolean call(ChartDataEntity ChartDataEntity) {
                        return ChartDataEntity.getDate() != null; // to filter out data without Date.
                    }
                })
                .toList()
                .compose(fragment.bindToLifecycle())
                .doOnNext(new Action1<List<ChartDataEntity>>() {
                    @Override
                    public void call(List<ChartDataEntity> stockEntities) {
                        mBus.post(new OnChartDataReceivedEvent(TAG, stockEntities, ticker, exchange,
                                chartTimePeriod));
                    }
                })
                .subscribe(new Action1<List<ChartDataEntity>>() {
                    @Override
                    public void call(List<ChartDataEntity> stockEntities) {
                    }
                }, new Action1<Throwable>() {
                    @Override
                    public void call(Throwable throwable) {
                        Log.e("TAG", throwable.getMessage());
                    }
                });
    }

public Observable<List<ChartDataEntity>> getChartStockData(@NonNull String ticker, @NonNull String exchange) {
        return Observable.fromCallable(() -> {
            Log.i(TAG + Utils.getCurrentThreadInfo(), "Getting stockChart");
            Response response = mGoogleFinanceWebInterface.getChartStockData(ticker, exchange,
                    GoogleFinanceWebInterface.INTERVAL_DEFAULT, GoogleFinanceWebInterface.PERIOD_DEFAULT,
                    new GoogleFinanceWebInterface.ChartParameters());
            String strResponse = responseMapper.call(response);
            return StockUtils.convertResponseToChartData(strResponse);
        });
    }
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: you are getting a timeout exception from you connection. test the api call in postman and see if it works

Comment: Yes I know that I'm getting a timeout exception. I want to handle that in my Rx code. I am expecting every error in throwable call of subscribe method. But why does this one crash instead of going to subscribe throwable call.

Comment: are you sure you are calling onError at RestAdapter.java:395 correctly?

Comment: RestAdapter.java is inside Retrofit library! I don't have control over it. And I don't want to do anything there. I want to handle it in my code no matter which exception Retrofit throws. I'm doing something wrong in Rx code. That's what I need to find. any help?

Comment: Your problem is in getChartStockData.  That's where you're throwing an exception.  You need to catch it and handle it there-  either by calling an error function, by retrying, or by whatever other behavior makes sense.  No further help is possible without that code

Comment: @Gabe Sechan I have added getChartStockData() method implemetation above in my question. Can you please check it and tell me what could be done?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you need to start ***mainThread*** just before second ***compose*** operator it's because Retrofit related execution should be on same thread.

so add this line

```
.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
```

just after `toList()`

Comment: I actually had solved it handling the exception in onErrorReturn callback. I was not able to do it in onError because it was a compositeException, which I think recently solved in RxJava but not yet included in RxAndroid. Thank you for your answer. But in my case retrofit calls were handled in background and it's working perfect. The exception is raised when there is a problem with the internet/server which we need to handle anyway. Thank you.

Comment: it's fine, actually i had same exception few days back and i solved it way i mentioned in answer. so i thought it would also be helpful to you.